# Hover on div makes other elements disappear

Tags: html, css

I created three divs and aligned them in a row. I wanted to make their height increase once the mouse hovers over them. For instance, I hover my mouse over "div2" and "div2" expands vertically. When I remove my mouse from the div area, it collapses back. The thing is, everything works fine but for some reason when I hover over "div1" it expands vertically but the rest two divs disappear. When I hover over "div2" it expands vertically with "div1" still being there but now "div3" disappears. When I hover over "div3" everything works fine. I have a feeling this has to do with the "position" attribute.

Thank you

```css
#div1 {
  width: 416px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 95px;
  left: -290px;
  background-color: red;
  text-indent: -40px;
}

#div2 {
  width: 417.5px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  left: 126px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div3 {
  width: 416px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 543.5px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1:hover {
  width: 416px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: -290px;
  background-color: red;
  text-indent: -40px;
}

#div2:hover {
  width: 417.5px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  left: 126px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div3:hover {
  width: 416px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  top: -55px;
  left: 543.5px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Some text</div>
<div id="div2">Some text</div>
<div id="div3">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would approach your question...

1. Wrap the divs in a new container and give it `position: relative;`
2. Position the divs absolutely and use `bottom` instead of `top` - this will allow the divs to expand upward. The `bottom` property is the `95px` from the top + the height of the `div` (`40px`)
3. Simplify your CSS by removing duplicated properties.

**Example**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -135px;
}

#div1 {
  width: 416px;
  height: 40px;
  left: -290px;
  background-color: red;
  text-indent: -40px;
}

#div2 {
  width: 417.5px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 126px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div3 {
  width: 416px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 543.5px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1:hover,
#div2:hover,
#div3:hover {
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="div1">Some text</div>
  <div id="div2">Some text</div>
  <div id="div3">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:top` try with demo

```css
.hover {
    width: 24%;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #5A98A4;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.hover:hover {
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    transition-duration:1s;
    -moz-transition-duration:1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -ms-transition-duration:1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover"></div>
<div class="hover"></div>
<div class="hover"></div>
```

i have applied this to your code also check with this snippet too

```css
#div1 {
  width: 416px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
  background-color: red;
  text-indent: -40px;
}

#div2 {
  width: 417.5px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div3 {
  width: 416px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1:hover {
  width: 416px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
  background-color: red;
  text-indent: -40px;
}

#div2:hover {
  width: 417.5px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div3:hover {
  width: 416px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Some text</div>
<div id="div2">Some text</div>
<div id="div3">Some text</div>
```